# How to remove white border in stacked column google chart?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-visualization

I want to remove the white border in stacked column google chart.
Can someone help me?

this is what I mean : [my current chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9r1B.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a `'style'` [column role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#what-roles-are-available) to *remove white border*

to actually *remove* it, you could use...

`stroke-width: 0;`

or

`stroke-color: transparent;`

but this will allow the background color to show through,
and will look the same visually on a white background

---

instead, recommend using the same `stroke-color` as being used for each series

see following working snippet, a `DataView` is used to add two `'style'` columns

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var seriesColors = ['#0097A7', '#26C6DA'];

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y1');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y2');
  data.addRows([
      ['Jan', 10500000, 1500000],
      ['Feb', 4500000, 400000],
      ['Mar', 7000000,800000],
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1, {
      type: 'string',
      role: 'style',
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        return 'stroke-color: ' + seriesColors[0];
      }
    }, 2, {
      type: 'string',
      role: 'style',
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        return 'stroke-color: ' + seriesColors[1];
      }
    }
  ]);

  var options = {
    colors: seriesColors,
    height: 400,
    isStacked: true,
    legend: 'none',
    width: 400
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);
  chart.draw(view, options);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: note: this could also be achieved via _css_ on the chart's `<rect>` elements, or some other manual _javascript_ -- but using standard options, as above, will ensure style comes through when using other methods, such as [`getImageURI`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing)

Comment: I try the way you suggest, but it still does not work, here's a script that I use, whether you wish to correct?

https://jsfiddle.net/ymwjmu18/

I really need your help, it must be done before weekend :(

Comment: Any workaround for React Google Charts https://react-google-charts.com/bar-chart#stacked-bar-chart-with-multiple-series ??

Comment: you can use the style column role in react